# Migration from terms facet to terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to migrate terms facet

```
{
  "facets" : {
    "facet_name" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "location",
          "script" : "return doc['location'].value == \"UA\""
        }
      }
    }
}
```

to terms aggregation

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "agg_name" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "location",
          "script" : "return doc['location'].value == \"UA\""
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Facet works fine on elastic (I've tested on 1.1.2 and 1.5.2)

But aggregation throws an exception 
org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutionException: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException[-1]

According to issue description https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11728 such behaviour appears because of "value" script is used by aggregation when explicit "field" found.

For facets scripts are traditional.

How to disable "value" nature of this script and make it works like in facet?

Thanks in advance!

---

PS: I can not use filtering (include / exclude), exclusion rules should be declared in script, same as for facet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found workaround by modifying script and removing "field" from agg:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "agg_name" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : "if (_source.location == \"UA\") {return _source.location} else {return null}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```